The keys +, -, and left control not work
The + - and left control key have stopped to work.
I use Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, 64 bits.
Keyboard layout US.
Stiky keys are not actived.
xev gives for - key
FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967248 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

and for + key
FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967248 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

somebody knows how I can solve this awkward situation? Two days ago works perfectly.
